# Any techniques to make css validate some property that fix IE to be compatible to be passed

Tags: cross-browser, css

I'm using some CSS properties that does not support in CSS 2.1. For example, -moz-border-radius, box-shadow, zoom, filter,.... make me fail with the CSS validation.

So are there any techniques to make the CSS validator to ignore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Microsoft Propreitary attributes , you can keep them in conditional comments this way:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
    /* Use all the non-standard Microsoft Propreitary attributes */
    body {zoom: 1; filter: none;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

If you are using stuff in stylesheets, then you can do this way:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie6.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This validates perfectly in W3C. Use this code to check:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <!--[if IE 6]>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Use all the non-standard Microsoft Propreitary attributes */
            body {zoom: 1; filter: none;}
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Validate by Direct Input: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

For others, you can set an option for **Vendor Extentions** to just display warnings in the CSS Validator.

[image]

Comment: but I wrote them in my stylesheet. How to do that in .css file @Praveen Kumar?

Comment: You can give a separate stylesheet @tepkenvannkorn. I will update the answer with how to include that too! :)

Comment: And moreover, those vendor / browser specific attributes will **never** validate, so there is no need of validation and it is better to keep them aside. :)